# XML to one level php array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I want to convert this xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<levela xmlns="https://restapi" version="1.0.0">
 <levelb>
   <levelc>
     <var1>01</var1>
     <var2>String1</var2>
   </levelc>
   <levelc>
     <var1>02</var1>
     <var2>String2</var2>
   </levelc>
   <levelc>
     <var1>08</var1>
     <var2>String3</var2>
   </levelc>
 </levelb>
</levela>
```

to this php array:

```
array(
    '01' => 'String1',
    '02' => 'String2',
    '08' => 'String3'
  )
```

I tried in many ways, but it's more difficult than I thought (for me). I hope someone can help me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "write my code" type question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy task with `SimpleXML`:

Load the XML into a SimpleXML object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $string );
```

Perform a `foreach()` loop through all `<issuer>` nodes and add `<issuername>` child node text value to your array using `<issuerid>` as key:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $xml->directory->issuer as $node )
{
    $result[ $node->issuerid->__toString() ] = $node->issuername->__toString();
}

print_r( $result );
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [01] => ABN Amro Bank
    [02] => ASN Bank
    [08] => Friesland Bank
)
```

`SimpleXML` return an object, so you need to cast as string node values with `->toString()` method to add it as string.

---

- Read more about [SimpleXML](http://php.net/en/simplexml)

Comment: Apparently the last entry in the array should be `[08] => 'Friesland Bank'` , you may have to change a bit your code.

Comment: @Loufylouf Yes, you are right. I did not see the use of `issuerid` as key. Thank you for the catch! Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follwong little trick to first get an array.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

The result of this will be an array representing exactly the XML structure, like that :

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.0.0
        )

    [directory] => Array
        (
            [issuer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [issuerid] => 01
                            [issuername] => ABN Amro Bank
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [issuerid] => 02
                            [issuername] => ASN Bank
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [issuerid] => 08
                            [issuername] => Friesland Bank
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

With just a little bit of work, you will be able to build the array you want.